# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions

Tags: java, java-ee, selenium

Tengo el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:339)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
```

Estoy haciendo un bot para redes sociales, y estoy utilizando las librerias de Selenium, el bot funciona perfectamente en una Java Application, pero cuando copio el codigo a una Web Application donde tengo un Servlet escuchando a mi aplication Android , cuando ejecuto el Servlet y este llama a el codigo de el bot que utiliza Selenium, este lanza el error de arriba en esta linea de codigo:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\manue\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

He leido que podia ser debido a la version de guava, pero mi version de guava esta completamente actualizada y no se porque me puede estar generando este error.

En mi pom.xml de maven tengo las siguientes dependencias, entre ellas las de Selenium que incluye la ultima version de guava.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Dejo un pantallazo de la estructura de mi proyecto por si sirve de ayuda.
[image: Estructura Proyecto]

Comment: Ciertamente la excepción `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` hace referencia a problemas relacionados con la versión de las librerías, en este caso mencionas que tienes las librerías actualizadas, este puede ser el problema, que tal vez la versión requerida para tu proyecto no debe ser la más actualizada sino una anterior, prueba cambiando la versión a releases anteriores hasta encontrar la adecuada.

Comment: Algo no encaja. Dices usar la versión 3.10.0, pero el error no parece coincidir con esa versión. Aquí tienes el código fuente de DriverService para esa versión, y la llamada a Preconditions.checkState tiene una signatura diferente. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.10.0/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/service/DriverService.java

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestras prontas respuestas, voy a intentar e investigar lo que me decís.

Comment: Revisa la carpeta WEB-INF/lib de tu aplicación tal y como está desplegada en el servidor, y revisa también que el jar de guava no esté en alguna carpeta de librerías a nivel de servidor.

Comment: He estado probando versiones diferentes de guava , he probado todas desde la 24.0-jre a la 18.0 y con todas me reporta el mismo error.

Comment: El caso es que según dice Pablo es cierto que no encaja con el error que dice en github para el método de findExecutable() , de la linea 124, at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124).    Según el cual el problema seria que no encuentra el ejecutable del Driver, pero si lo tengo en la ruta que le indico en el System.setProperty , podría ser que al estarlo ejecutando en un servidor Glassfish en Netbeans no coja las rutas del equipo y por eso no encuentre el ejecutable???

Comment: También he pensado que quizás pudiera ser que el Glassfish que tengo corriendo el programa dentro de netbeans , por algún motivo no tenga permiso de acceso a las rutas del pc que sean externas al proyecto, pero he cambiado el driver tambien a dentro de el proyecto pasando le luego como referencia la ruta relativa a el proyecto pero sigue sin ir, nose, jajaja ayuda porfavor!

Comment: Algunos me indicáis que revise el contenido de mi carpeta WEB-INF/lib pero el caso es que mi carpeta esta vacía por defecto, así me la creo Netbeans , donde si veo reflejadas las librerías es en Dependencies https://i.stack.imgur.com/jajaU.png